# Private Key error in Saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate with Self-Signed Cert

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I would like to test this implementation using self-signed certificates. I'm using the MVC implementation and am running into `The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error`.

Debugging shows the error occurs in `Saml2SignedXml.ComputeSignature(...)` at `line 36: ComputeSignature()`, which is inherited from Microsoft's SignedMxl and I can't step into it.

Saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate shows `HasPrivateKey = true`, but an error for the PrivateKey property: `Saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate.PrivateKey` threw an exception of type `System.NotSupportedException`.

I see the private key in the same property when using the provide ITFoxtec cert.

I am using a self-signed cert because the `tfoxtec.identity.saml2.testidpcore_Certificate.pfx` cert causes a `Incorrect URI format` error in MVC.

Honestly, I don't think this is a code problem so much as a certificate problem, but I'm not sure where to look at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use another self-signed certificate.

It is possible to create at self-signed certificate in .NET core or .NET 5.0 like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create self-signed certificate with subject name. .
/// </summary>
/// <param name="subjectName">Certificate subject name, example: "CN=my-certificate, O=some-organisation".</param>
/// <param name="expiry">Certificate expiry, default 365 days.</param>
public static Task<X509Certificate2> CreateSelfSignedCertificateAsync(this string subjectName, TimeSpan? expiry = null)
{
    using (var rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        var certRequest = new CertificateRequest(subjectName, rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, false));

        certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(certRequest.PublicKey, false));

        certRequest.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509KeyUsageExtension(
                X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyAgreement,
                false));

        var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        return Task.FromResult(certRequest.CreateSelfSigned(now.AddDays(-1), now.Add(expiry ?? TimeSpan.FromDays(365))));
    }
}
```

The code is from ITfoxtec.Identity [X509Certificate2Extensions.cs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity/blob/master/src/Extensions/X509Certificate2Extensions.cs) and the code is e.g. used in [FoxIDs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs/blob/master/src/FoxIDs.Shared/Extensions/X509Certificate2Extensions.cs).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wasn't able to figure out how to use that library to create a cert file in a timely manner.

I did create a valid cert that works using the instructions at:
https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/

Your response did confirm that I should keep at it with creating a valid cert.